# Neo4j Java API - schema index range lookup?

Tags: java, neo4j

Neo4j 2.3 introduced the ability to use schema label indexes in range lookups. In Cypher using this feature is simple, ex:

```
MATCH (n:SomeLabel) WHERE n.prop > 200 AND n.prop < 300
```

As expected that query would use an index for SomeLabel(prop).

My question is, is there a way to replicate this with the standard Neo4j Java API? I can use GraphDatabaseService.findNodes to do a single value schema index lookup, but I don't see any method that allows for a range query.

I realize I can run a Cypher query with the Java API to accomplish this, but since my project only uses the low-level Java API I'd like to avoid that and keep it consistent, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Neo4j's documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html) you can't find a node using a property range.

So, to do what you want to do, you can match every nodes having the desired label, and check the value range on Java side:

Assuming `gdb` is your GraphDatabaseService, and `Labels`your labels enum:

```
ResourceIterator<Node> nodes = gdb.findNodes(Labels.SomeLabel);
Set<Node> result = new HashSet<Node>();
while(nodes.hasNext()){
    Node n = nodes.next();
    // I cast only to ensure I really get an integer
    int prop = Integer.valueOf(n.getProperty("prop").toString()); 
    if(prop > 200 && prop < 300){
        result.add(n);
    }
}
//And here you can return your Set, or do whatever you want with it
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. That wouldn't really be good to use in my case because  for my use-case it is important the index gets used and not every item and property has to be fetched and inspected.

If there is no way to do it with just the Java API, then I would probably just use Cypher like this which will properly utilize the schema index for the range lookup:

Result myResult = graphDb.execute( "MATCH (n:SomeLabel) WHERE n.prop > 200 AND n.prop < 300")

Comment: So I'm afraid the only way to do it will be to use `execute(String query)` method from GraphDatabaseService... you don't have any method to find nodes using a range or values

Comment: Yeah, it seems that's the case. It is unfortunate though now that range queries can take advantage of schema indexes. I hope they decide to add a method. It would be useful, IMHO.

Comment: Using the method I provided is not resource expensive you know, you only do one "query" to the database. So if they add a method doing that, it will probably be almost the same implementation.

Comment: It is very expensive, from my understanding. findNodes is just doing a full label scan, meaning that method has to analyze every single node with the label "SomeLabel". So for the use-case my question is based on, for every lookup it would have to analyze about 1 million nodes and their properties to come away with 100 or so it needs. With an indexed lookup, it's able to completely skip that and analyze significantly less nodes.

Comment: Also, just to clarify - if they were to add a method to do this, it would not be like that implementation. From looking through the codebase a bit, it would utilize DiskLayer's methods nodesGetFromInclusiveNumericIndexRangeSeek, nodesGetFromIndexRangeSeekByString, etc.